# Appropriately positioning annotations on stacked barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have annotated each bar on my stacked barplot but can't seem to get the annotations to be equivalent to the bar's position.

This is the code I have:

```
for i in ax_mult.patches:
  width,height=i.get_width(),i.get_height()
  x,z =i.get_xy()
  ax_mult.annotate(str(i.get_height()),(i.get_x()+.30*width,i.get_height()+.1*height))
```

This is what I am getting
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your main problem was that you placed the text in `y` direction effectively at `1.1 * i.get_height()`, without considering the initial offset `i.get_y()`.

Try this:

```
for i in ax_mult.patches:
    ix,iy=i.get_x(),i.get_y() ## gives you the bottom left of each patch
    width,height=i.get_width(),i.get_height() ## the width & height of each patch

    ## to place the annotation at the center (0.5, 0.5):
    ax.annotate(str(height),(ix+0.5*width, iy+0.5*height),ha="center",va="center")

    ## alternatively via ax.text():
    # ax.text(ix+.5*width,iy+.5*height,height,ha="center",va="center" )
```

Note that you may need to "play around" with good offsets, especially in y-direction. The `ha="center",va="center"` parameters align the text exactly at the chosen coordinate (both horizontally: ha and vertically: va), which comes in handy if you'd like to put the labels e.g. aligned below the top end of the patch:

```
ax.annotate(str(height),(ix+0.5*width, iy+1.0*height),ha="center",va="top")
```

Or just above the top end of the patch:

```
ax.annotate(str(height),(ix+0.5*width, iy+1.0*height),ha="center",va="bottom")
```